# How to overcome the cascade in Firebase Realtime Database rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Given the following data structure:

```
items
    categoryId1
        itemId1
            name
            amount
            dateAdded
        itemId2
            name
            amount
            dateAdded
    categoryId2
        itemId3
            name
            amount
            dateAdded
```

I'd like to set the following rules:

- If the user is logged-in using `foo@gmail.com` or `bar@gmail.com`, they should be able to add and update items.
- Other logged-in users should be able to update only the item's amount.

I've tried the following Realtime Database rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      "$categoryId": {
        "$itemId": {
          ".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password' && (auth.token.email === 'foo@gmail.com' || auth.token.email === 'bar@gmail.com')"
          "amount": {
            ".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, this doesn't allow `someone_else@gmail.com` to update the item's amount. The following promise gets rejected with "Permission Denied":

```
app
  .database()
  .ref(`items/${categoryId}`)
  .push({
    name,
    amount,
    dateAdded,
  })
```

I know that with Realtime Database, rules work from top-down, with shallower rules overriding deeper rules.

So, what's the idiomatic way to overcome this? Is it possible to achieve the requirements above using this data structure, or do I need to restructure my data?

Comment: As far as I can see this use-case should be possible, and at first glance your rules look fine to me. Can you edit your question to show the code for the write operation that doesn't work as you expect it to?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I found the issue by looking at the write code.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out! 

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `.write` needed to be under `$categoryId`, not under `$itemId`. Thanks Frank!